# Deleting remote branches using Magit

Tags: magit

I want to delete a remote branch. How can I do `git push origin --delete my-branch` in magit, to delete a remote branch?

Answer (score 2):

In Magit the command for deleting a remote branch is the same as for deleting a local branch, and its key binding is <kbd>b k</kbd>.

So to delete `my-branch` on `origin` you would type <kbd>b k</kbd> `origin/my-branch` <kbd>RET</kbd>.

---

Deleting the remote branch `origin/feature` involves two steps:

1. Actually deleting the branch on the remote repository.
2. Updating the cache in the local repository, which keeps track of the state of the remote repository.

Deleting a remote branch does **not** delete the corresponding local branch, `feature`. I.e., the local ref `refs/heads/feature` is not being deleted. What is being deleted is the "remote-tracking branch", represented in the local repository by the ref `refs/remotes/origin/feature`, which is a reference to the state of the remote branch.

There likely is a relationship between the branch `feature` and the remote-tracking branch `origin/feature`, but deleting one does not cause the other to be deleted. However `refs/remotes/origin/feature` is how the local repository keeps track of "`feature` on `origin`", so deleting the former should go in hand with deleting the latter.

When you delete a remote branch In Magit, then it prompts with `Delete origin/feature on the remote (not just locally)?`. The "not just locally" was added because a user might expect that only `refs/remotes/origin/feature` is deleted but not "`feature` on `origin`".

Deleting only `refs/remotes/origin/feature` only makes sense in very rare situations. Doing so would essentially make the local cache of the remote state incorrect and later fetching from the remote again would fix that defect, i.e., `refs/remotes/origin/feature` would be recreated.

Yet, some users expected, that that is what "deleting a remote branch" would do, so the warning was added. Unfortunately that warning led other users to believe that deleting a remote branch also causes the local branch to be deleted.

Comment: `b k` only removes the local one. The pushed remote branch still exists on Github

Comment: `b k` first tries to delete the remote branch using `git push origin --delete my-branch` and if and only if that fails (e.g. because you don't have write permissions), then it deletes the respective local ref only.

Comment: @Student Errr... Just so you know, tarsius is the chief maintainer of magit. :-)

Comment: That is scary behavior, now I know why part of the prompt for removing a remote branch says "....(not just locally)". I love magit, but that could be disastrous (deleting a local branch when you meant only to delete a remote), no? Love magit by the way, thank you!!

Comment: @Joe The local branch is not deleted, see the updates answer.